# BufferedReader sometimes read text, sometimes doesn't

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read from a .java the methods I have on it, also the classes, I'm using taggs to identify them and stored them, the problem is that using BufferedReader sometimes just doesn't work, the buffer skips a lot of lines for a reason that I can't understand, sometimes when checking the file by myself I just put random spaces between lines, and that fixes some parts, but I can't get the Buffer read all my text without skipping anything, my code so far is like this:

```
    public class ReadFile {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numclas=0,numbase=0,numbaseagr=0,numbmet=0,numag=0;
        String mt="//MT";
        String[] nomclass2 = new String[10];
        String[] nommetodo2 = new String[50];
        boolean metodo=false;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
          in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\Program.java"));
          String read = null;
          while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
          read = in.readLine();
          String[] splited = read.trim().split("\\s+");

          for(int i=0;i<splited.length;i++){
            System.out.println(splited[i]);

            if(splited[i].equals("class")){
               nomclass2[numclas]=splited[i+1];
               numclas=numclas+1;
        }

           if (splited[i].equals(mt)){
            metodo=true;
        }

            if (splited[i].equals("public")){
                if (splited[i+1].equals("static")){
                    nommetodo2[numbmet]=splited[i+3];
                    numbmet=numbmet+1;
                }
                if (splited[i+1].equals("int")||splited[i+1].equals("double")||splited[i+1].equals("String")||splited[i+1].equals("boolean")){
                nommetodo2[numbmet]=splited[i+2];
                numbmet=numbmet+1;
                }

        if (splited[i].equals("int")||splited[i].equals("double")||splited[i].equals("String")||splited[i].equals("boolean")){
                nommetodo2[numbmet]=splited[i+1];
                numbmet=numbmet+1;
                }
        metodo=false;
        }

        if ((splited[i].equals("int")||splited[i].equals("double")||splited[i].equals("String")||splited[i].equals("boolean"))&&metodo){   
                nommetodo2[numbmet]=splited[i+1];
                numbmet=numbmet+1;
                metodo=false;
                }

        }


}
 } catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
try {
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
 }
```

Now let me show you the .java I'm trying to read:

```
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import java.io.*;
 //Main file of the program 1
 public class Program1 {
  //MT
  public static void main (String args []) {
  DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("##.##");
  System.out.println("How many data do you want to insert?");
  int num=Leer.Int();
  Fila lista=new Fila();
  Fila lista2=new Fila();
  double x=0.0;
  for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
  x=Leer.Double();
  lista.addNum(x);
        }
    double prom=0.0;
    double desv=0.0;
    prom=lista.getprom();
    desv=lista.getdevst();
    System.out.println("The mean for column 1 is: "+format.format(prom));
    System.out.println("The Std.Dev for column 1 is: "+format.format(desv));
    System.out.println("How many data do you want to insert?");
num=Leer.Int();
x=0.0;
for(int i=0;i<num;i++) {
x=Leer.Double();
lista2.addNum(x);
        }
    prom=0.0;
desv=0.0;
prom=lista2.getprom();
desv=lista2.getdevst();
    System.out.println("The mean for column 2 is: "+format.format(prom));
System.out.println("The Std.Dev for column 2 is: "+format.format(desv));
    }
}
```

And the result when I print the array

```
Date:
12/12/12
import
java.text.DecimalFormat;
//Main
file
of
the
program
1
//MT
DecimalFormat
format=new
DecimalFormat("##.##");
so on...
```

See how in the //MT the Buffer skips a lot of lines, a lot of this is happening (see how it ignores the first lines of the program), and I don't know how to fix it, because sometimes when I try to "fix it" and add some spaces in the lines, I get a nullpointer and the program ends.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a partial answer - at the very least your program is skipping every other line:

```
while ((read = in.readLine()) != null)
```

will read a line from the file. The line is immediately discarded because the immediately following statement:

```
read = in.readLine();
```

reads and processes the next line from the file.

*(also, 'splited' should be 'splitted' along with numerous other spelling mistakes but they're not really affecting your program, just it's readability :-))*

Comment: Tnx :) I know that I have a lot of spelling mistakes sorry for that xP, so should I get rid of that statement? the one that I have in the while will do just fine by itself?

Comment: Yes, just use the readLine in the while loop. If you (temporarily) print out every line before you process it you will be able to see what you're doing.

Comment: Dude, is incredible how stupid I was, I just removed that line, and now the program reads everything, man, I was over thinking to much, Thank you so much man, you saved me.